# Show a toast (using alarmmanager)

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I've a service that runs after android starts. I'd like show a toast every days at 9am. The problem is: how can I implement the code (alarmamanger within service)?

Start service after boot:

```
public class AutoStart extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent();
serviceIntent.setAction("com.example.startatboot.UnUsedService");
context.startService(serviceIntent);

}
}


public class Service extends Service {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
return null;
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {
super.onCreate();
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
super.onStart(intent, startId);

Toast.makeText(UnUsedService.this, "Start Alarm", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}};

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)     context.getSystemService  (Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, new Intent(context,     MyClass.class),      PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),     AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace your code with my code,

```
public class Service extends Service {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
return null;
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {
super.onCreate();
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
super.onStart(intent, startId);

Toast.makeText(UnUsedService.this, "Start Alarm", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}};

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)     context.getSystemService  (Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, new Intent(context,     AlarmReceiver.class),      PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),     AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
```

Now create a new class AlarmReceiver in the same package and add the following code to it.

```
 public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm worked.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
 }
```

Now define it in the `PendingIntent` of the `Alarm`.

Add following code in the manifest file,

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" />
```

Now run your application. that's it. It will definitely show a toast at 9.

Let me know if it worked or not.

Comment: I added autostart class (to start my service). How I define PendingIntent of the alarm? sorry and thanks!

Comment: you have already defined the pendingIntent in the AlarmManager. check your above code. just replace the receiver name in the intent of it.

Comment: Sorry but I don'understand :-/ the code "Calendar.getInstance();" where should be put? And where I put pendingIntent? be patience please... from many days I study and I too tired...

Comment: I have edited my answer completely. It will definitely solve your problem. just replace your code with mine. let me know, if it solved your issue or not.

Comment: Thanks. Main app remains by waiting and does not run. (A questions: context is a variable? I need to define it like private "static final Context context = null;"?

Comment: what this means: _Main app remains by waiting and does not run._?

Comment: I start runs with eclipse, I see white mainactivity (no logs error). About "context", context is a variable? (in Service class)

Comment: you should use **getApplicationContext()** instead of just **context**.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21079/discussion-between-pol-hallen-and-sahilmahajanmj)

Comment: which toast.? The toast would be displayed on the time you have specified.

Comment: I set time near 2 minutes from now and compile to emulator but I don't see any toast at time specified.

Comment: start this discussion in chat.